# Need slug field value as JDoe (for John Doe) in doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, slug

How can I set slug field  to JDoe (J-First char of first name, Doe - full last name);

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"firstName", "lastName"}, separator="??")
 * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
 */
```

Thanks!

Comment: I never used any Gedmo extension but if you need a slug from the manipulation of one or more fields (_i'm not sure but looking at the docs it seems not possible using the built-in handler annotation options_) I think that the simpler way is to create a new parameter like `fullNameSlug` and inside a `setFullNameSlug()` (_or externally in a service_) you can create what you need to then assign that parameter to the `@Gedmo\Slug` annotation.

Comment: There is something interesting in the documentation called `handlers` https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/doc/sluggable.md#basic-usage-examples if you want to only use `Gedmo`. Otherwise you could done this by a doctrine listener too

Comment: I think you should consider the 3rd method of trix's answer

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1

I have not tried the following, but it is probably the snippet you are looking for. git it a try and let me know if it works:

```
class SomeEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"getFirstNameSlugged", "lastName"}, separator="??")
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    private function getFirstNameFirstLetter()
    {
        return substr ($this->firstName, 0 , 1);
    }

    private function getFirstNameSlugged()
    {
        return ucfirst (getFirstNameFirstLetter());
    }

}
```

## Method 2

in your **Entity** use a `setSlug()` method:

```
class SomeEntity
{
    const SEPERATOR = '??';

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"firstName", "lastName"}, separator="??")
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    private function getFirstNameFirstLetter()
    {
        return substr ($this->firstName, 0 , 1);
    }

    private function getFirstNameSlugged()
    {
        return ucfirst (getFirstNameFirstLetter());
    }

    private function getLastNameSlugged()
    {
        return ucfirst ($this->getLastName());
    }

    public function setSlug()
    {
        $this->slug = $this->getFirstNameSlugged() . self::SEPERATOR . $this->getLastNameSlugged();

        return $this->slug;
    }
}
```

and in your **Controller**:

```
$entity = new SomeEntity;
$entity->setSlug();

$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```

## Method 3

in your **Entity**, create a method and set it in your **Controller**:

```
class SomeEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @Gedmo\Slug(fields={"firstName", "lastName"}, separator="??")
     * @ORM\Column(name="slug", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
     */
    private $slug;

    private function getFirstNameFirstLetter()
    {
        return substr ($this->firstName, 0 , 1);
    }

    private function getFirstNameSlugged()
    {
        return ucfirst (getFirstNameFirstLetter());
    }

    private function getLastNameSlugged()
    {
        return ucfirst ($this->getLastName());
    }

    public generateSlug()
    {
        $slug = $this->getFirstNameSlugged() . self::SEPERATOR . $this->getLastNameSlugged();

        return $slug;
    } 
}
```

and in your **Controller**:

```
$entity = new SomeEntity;

$callable = array('AppBundle\Entity\SomeEntity', 'generateSlug');
$sluggableListener = new \Gedmo\Sluggable\SluggableListener();
$sluggableListener->setTransliterator($callable);

$em->persist($entity);
$em->flush();
```